# Sequelize - Reset auto increment after seed:undo:all

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, auto-increment

I'm using PostgreSQL with Sequelize ORM, and I want that after deleting all seeders and creating them again (sequelize db:seed:undo:all, sequelize db:seed:all) their auto increment will reset to 0.

Cannot find a solution, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but this is how i solved the problem.

This is the Down() method of my seed for table "Schede":
I added to the options (third parameter) `truncate` and `cascade`.
Doc: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html)

```
  down: async (queryInterface, seq) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Schede', null, { truncate: true, cascade: true })
  }
```

Comment: Your doc link seems to have rotted. The [QueryInterface documentation page is here now](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~queryinterface).

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways that you can reset the sequence to 0.

1. `ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq RESTART WITH 0;`. This command will set the next value of the sequence to 0, so the next statement will use 1.
2. `TRUNCATE TABLE product RESTART IDENTITY;`. This will delete all the rows in the product table.

Here is the sequelize code:

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

// Reset auto increment for a specific table
await sequelize.query("ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq RESTART WITH 0", { type: QueryTypes.RAW });

// Truncate table and reset auto increment
await sequelize.query("TRUNCATE TABLE product RESTART IDENTITY", { type: QueryTypes.RAW });
```